# Capture data from user in dialogflow throw nodejs

Tags: dialogflow-cx

im having some issues in order to capture data that the user write in dialogflow. I need to capture that data in order to replace a query to a sql server to provide information to the user that is asking. For example.

user: can you give me some information of the process "name process"
dialog flow: of course you need a detail of the "name process" process. [data from sql, id of the process, etc...]

In order to this have a code in nodejs with the queries to the database but right now it's hardcoded the name of the process, i need to find a way to capture that "name process" from the user and replace a key word in my query. My code is this one.

```
/*

Copyright 2023 Benjamin Nicolas Hambra */ const express = require("express"); const { WebhookClient } = require("dialogflow-fulfillment"); const { Connection, Request } = require("tedious"); const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

const config = { server: 'DESKTOP-P35PQ8K', authentication: { type: 'default', options: { userName: 'sa', password: 'Benja2310$', }, }, options: { encrypt: false, // Use encryption if you are on Microsoft Azure database: 'InNoTimeRPAv2', rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion: true, }, };

// Funca app.get("/", function (req, res) { res.send("Funca"); });

function executeSQL(sql, callback) { const connection = new Connection(config); connection.connect(); connection.on("connect", (err) => { if (err) { console.error("Conexion fallida: ", err); return callback(err, null); }

const request = new Request(sql, (err, rowCount, rows) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error("Query no exitoso: ", err.message);
    return callback(err, null);
  }
  // NOTE: Uncomment to see complete Object
  // console.log(JSON.stringify(rows));

  const result = [];      
  rows.forEach((row) => {
    const entry = {};
    row.forEach((element) => {
      const colName = element.metadata.colName;
      const colValue = element.value;
      entry[colName] = colValue;
    });
    result.push(entry);
  });
  callback(null, { rowCount, result });
});

connection.execSql(request);

}); }

// Webhook app.post("/webhook", (req, res) => { const agent = new WebhookClient({ request: req, response: res });

function queryDatabase(callback) { executeSQL( "SELECT ProcesoDescripcion FROM Proceso;", (err, rows, rowCount) => { if (err) { console.error("Query no exitoso: ", err); callback(err, null); } console.log("Data: " + JSON.stringify(rows)); callback(null, JSON.stringify(rows)); } ); }

function queryDatabase2(callback) { executeSQL( "DECLARE @CurrentDate DATE = GETDATE(); DECLARE @FirstDayOfMonth DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, -2, DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @CurrentDate), 0))); DECLARE @LastDayOfMonth DATE = DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @CurrentDate) + 1, 0)); SELECT @FirstDayOfMonth AS FIRST_DAY, @LastDayOfMonth AS LAST_DAY, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT processname) FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[Jobs] j2 WHERE j2.jobstartdt >= @FirstDayOfMonth AND j2.jobstartdt <= @LastDayOfMonth) AS OPERATIVE, COUNT(1) AS EXECUTED, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[Jobs] j2 WHERE j2.jobstartdt >= @FirstDayOfMonth AND j2.jobstartdt <= @LastDayOfMonth AND jobstatus = 'Completed') AS COMPLETED, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[Jobs] j2 WHERE j2.jobstartdt >= @FirstDayOfMonth AND j2.jobstartdt <= @LastDayOfMonth AND jobstatus = 'Terminated') AS EXCEPTIONS, (SELECT ROUND(SUM(b.processtimesaving), 2) FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[BusinessData] b INNER JOIN [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[Jobs] jj ON jj.processid = b.processid WHERE jj.jobstartdt >= @FirstDayOfMonth AND jj.jobstartdt <= @LastDayOfMonth AND jj.jobid IN (SELECT DISTINCT jobid FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[TransactionItems])) AS HOURS_SAVED, (SELECT CONCAT(b.currency, ROUND(SUM(b.processcostsaving), 2)) FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[BusinessData] b INNER JOIN [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[Jobs] jj ON jj.processid = b.processid WHERE jj.jobstartdt >= @FirstDayOfMonth AND jj.jobstartdt <= @LastDayOfMonth AND jj.jobid IN (SELECT DISTINCT jobid FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[TransactionItems]) GROUP BY b.currency) AS TOTAL_BENEFITS FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[Jobs] j1 WHERE j1.jobstartdt >= @FirstDayOfMonth AND j1.jobstartdt <= @LastDayOfMonth;", (err, rows, rowCount) => { if (err) { console.error("Query no exitoso: ", err); callback(err, null); } console.log("Data: " + JSON.stringify(rows)); callback(null, JSON.stringify(rows)); } ); }

function queryDatabase3(callback) { executeSQL( "SELECT 'Recepción radicación y enrutamiento de órdenes', j3.jobstartdt, ROUND(DATEDIFF(SECOND, j3.jobenddt, j3.jobstartdt) * -1 / 60.0, 2) AS duration, j3.jobstatus, " + "(SELECT COUNT(TransactionItems.id) FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[TransactionItems] WHERE jobid = " + "(SELECT jobid FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[Jobs] WHERE internalid = " + "(SELECT MAX(internalid) FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[Jobs] WHERE Jobs.processid = " + "(SELECT DISTINCT b.processid FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[BusinessData] b WHERE alias = 'Recepción radicación y enrutamiento de órdenes')))) AS transactions_quantity, " + "(SELECT COUNT(TransactionItems.id) FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[TransactionItems] WHERE jobid = " + "(SELECT jobid FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[Jobs] WHERE internalid = " + "(SELECT MAX(internalid) FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[Jobs] WHERE Jobs.processid = " + "(SELECT DISTINCT b.processid FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[BusinessData] b WHERE alias = 'Recepción radicación y enrutamiento de órdenes')) AND completed IS NULL AND exception IS NOT NULL)) " + "AS transaction_quantity_errors, (SELECT currency FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[BusinessData] WHERE processid = j3.processid) AS currency, " + "(SELECT ROUND((COUNT(ti.id) * (SELECT transactioncostsaving FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[BusinessData] WHERE processid = j3.processid)), 2) " + "FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[Jobs] j INNER JOIN [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[TransactionItems] ti ON j.jobid = ti.jobid " + "WHERE j.internalid = j3.internalid) + (SELECT ROUND((COUNT(j.jobid) * (SELECT processcostsaving FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[BusinessData] " + "WHERE processid = j3.processid)), 2) FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[Jobs] j WHERE j.internalid = j3.internalid) AS saving_money, " + "(SELECT ROUND((COUNT(ti.id) * (SELECT transactiontimesaving FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[BusinessData] WHERE processid = j3.processid)), 2) " + "FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[Jobs] j INNER JOIN [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[TransactionItems] ti ON j.jobid = ti.jobid " + "WHERE j.internalid = j3.internalid) + (SELECT ROUND((COUNT(j.jobid) * (SELECT processtimesaving FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[BusinessData] " + "WHERE processid = j3.processid)), 2) FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[Jobs] j WHERE j.internalid = j3.internalid) AS saving_fte, 'hours FTE', " + "(SELECT jobstartdt FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[Jobs] WHERE internalid = " + "(SELECT MAX(j3.internalid) FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[Jobs] j3 WHERE j3.processid = " + "(SELECT DISTINCT b.processid FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[BusinessData] b WHERE alias = 'Recepción radicación y enrutamiento de órdenes') " + "AND j3.internalid < (SELECT MAX(j4.internalid) FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[Jobs] j4 WHERE j4.processid = " + "(SELECT DISTINCT b.processid FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[BusinessData] b WHERE alias = 'Recepción radicación y enrutamiento de órdenes')))) " + "AS PREVIOUS_STARTED, (SELECT COUNT(tt.id) FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[TransactionItems] tt WHERE tt.jobid = " + "(SELECT jobid FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[Jobs] WHERE internalid = " + "(SELECT MAX(j3.internalid) FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[Jobs] j3 WHERE j3.processid = " + "(SELECT DISTINCT b.processid FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[BusinessData] b WHERE alias = 'Recepción radicación y enrutamiento de órdenes') " + "AND j3.internalid < (SELECT MAX(j4.internalid) FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[Jobs] j4 WHERE j4.processid = " + "(SELECT DISTINCT b.processid FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[BusinessData] b WHERE alias = 'Recepción radicación y enrutamiento de órdenes'))))) " + "AS PREVIOUS_TRANSACTIONS, (SELECT COUNT(tt.id) FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[TransactionItems] tt WHERE tt.jobid = " + "(SELECT jobid FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[Jobs] WHERE internalid = " + "(SELECT MAX(j3.internalid) FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[Jobs] j3 WHERE j3.processid = " + "(SELECT DISTINCT b.processid FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[BusinessData] b WHERE alias = 'Recepción radicación y enrutamiento de órdenes') " + "AND j3.internalid < (SELECT MAX(j4.internalid) FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[Jobs] j4 WHERE j4.processid = " + "(SELECT DISTINCT b.processid FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[BusinessData] b WHERE alias = 'Recepción radicación y enrutamiento de órdenes'))) " + "AND completed IS NULL AND exception IS NOT NULL)) AS PREVIOUS_ERRORS FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[Jobs] j3 WHERE j3.processid = " + "(SELECT DISTINCT b.processid FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[BusinessData] b WHERE alias = 'Recepción radicación y enrutamiento de órdenes') " + "AND j3.internalid = (SELECT MAX(j4.internalid) FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[Jobs] j4 WHERE j4.processid = " + "(SELECT DISTINCT b.processid FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[BusinessData] b WHERE alias = 'Recepción radicación y enrutamiento de órdenes'))", (err, rows, rowCount) => { if (err) { console.error("Query no exitoso: ", err); callback(err, null); } console.log("Data: " + JSON.stringify(rows)); callback(null, JSON.stringify(rows)); } ); }

function queryDatabase4(callback) { executeSQL( "SELECT t.keyvalue AS ID, t.status AS ESTADO, t.exceptionreason AS EXCEPTIONDETAIL, t.finished AS EXCEPTIONTIME FROM [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[TransactionItems] t INNER JOIN [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[Jobs] j ON t.jobid = j.jobid INNER JOIN [InNoTimeRPAv2].[rcf_staging].[BusinessData] b ON j.jobid = b.processid WHERE b.alias = 'Recepción radicación y enrutamiento de órdenes' AND completed IS NULL AND t.finished >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()) AND t.finished <= DATEADD(MONTH, 3, GETDATE());", (err, rows, rowCount) => { if (err) { console.error("Query no exitoso: ", err); callback(err, null); } console.log("Data: " + JSON.stringify(rows)); callback(null, JSON.stringify(rows)); } ); }

function queryHandler(agent) { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { queryDatabase((error, rows) => { if (error) { agent.add("An error occurred while querying the database."); reject(error); } else { resolve(rows); } }); }); }

function queryHandler2(agent) { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { queryDatabase2((error, rows) => { if (error) { agent.add("An error occurred while querying the database."); reject(error); } else { resolve(rows); } }); }); }

function queryHandler3(agent) { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { queryDatabase3((error, rows) => { if (error) { agent.add("An error occurred while querying the database."); reject(error); } else { resolve(rows); } }); }); }

function queryHandler4(agent) { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { queryDatabase4((error, rows) => { if (error) { agent.add("An error occurred while querying the database."); reject(error); } else { resolve(rows); } }); }); }

function updateAgentResponse(agent, response) { agent.add(response); }

function getDataFromSQLHandler(agent) { return queryHandler(agent).then((data) => { updateAgentResponse(agent, data); }); }

function getDataFromSQLHandler2(agent) { return queryHandler2(agent).then((data) => { updateAgentResponse(agent, data); }); }

function getDataFromSQLHandler3(agent) { return queryHandler3(agent).then((data) => { updateAgentResponse(agent, data); }); }

function getDataFromSQLHandler4(agent) { return queryHandler4(agent).then((data) => { updateAgentResponse(agent, data); }); }

function fallbackHandler(agent) { agent.add(Fallback ok); } function welcomeHandler(agent) { agent.add("Welcome ok");

}

async function capturarProceso(agent) { const userInput = agent.queryText; agent.add(userInput); }

const intentMap = new Map(); intentMap.set("LISTA-DE-PROCESOS", getDataFromSQLHandler); intentMap.set("REPORTE-GENERAL", getDataFromSQLHandler2); intentMap.set("DETALLE-PROCESO", getDataFromSQLHandler3); intentMap.set("DETALLE-ERRORES-PROCESO", getDataFromSQLHandler4); intentMap.set("Fallback", fallbackHandler); //intentMap.set("Welcome", welcomeHandler); intentMap.set("Welcome - next", capturarProceso); agent.handleRequest(intentMap); });

app.listen(3000, () => { console.log("Server is listening on port 3000"); });
```